# Disable Drag of MetroApps/Desktop ability on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui, windows-8-apps

I am trying to figure out how to complety disable the drag functionality of MetroApps/Desktop (not the whole drag and drop of files/folders) on Windows 8.1 so far no luck.

The only thing I could manage to find till now is to prevent the drag to close with those registry entries.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Switcher
MouseCloseThresholdPercent (REG_DWORD) 0
TouchCloseThresholdPercent (REG_DWORD) 0
```

But how can I completly disable this functionality?

Hope you can help me out.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is a core function of Win 8.1 and unlikely that you will be able to make it so.

Comment: @Joshua Because I am developing a kiosk application, and I dont want the user to be able to drag it around.

Comment: @RandRandom You should phrase your question(s) to be about the problem at hand, instead of about your attempted solution.  It helps avoid [XY Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/174452).

Comment: @techie007 I actually did phrase my current problem..., that I cannot disable it completly but I am stuck with those keys and cant find others.

Comment: Instead of trying to hack a solution.  Why can't you use Assigned Access which by default limits what can be done.

Comment: @Ramhound This seems to only work with MetroApps, I only have a windows application thats probably a good choice for a future solution but now I am kinda stuck with this.

Comment: "Please note that traditional desktop apps don’t provide the same level of security and therefore cannot be used in Assigned Access. **You will need Windows Embedded to lock a machine in a desktop application.**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't easily do that. However since you mentioned that you are developing a Kiosk mode you should switch the device to [Assigned Access](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/28/how-to-setup-assigned-access-in-windows-8-1-kiosk-mode.aspx) first

In assigned access many of the shortcuts ALT+F4 and CTRL+ALT+DEL are disabled and your app will run in full screen mode, which means there is no risk to being dragged around.

The hardware Windows button is disabled as well so you are guaranteed that your app always runs as the main app.

Comment: This seems to only work with MetroApps, I only have a windows application thats probably a good choice for a future solution but now I am kinda stuck with this.

Comment: "Please note that traditional desktop apps don’t provide the same level of security and therefore cannot be used in Assigned Access. **You will need Windows Embedded to lock a machine in a desktop application**."

Comment: @techie007 okay i get it, this is the wrong place to ask for help about hacking/tweaking the OS like I desire...